# Differential Equation Error

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The author of my textbook asks to verify that the function:

$$ y = \sqrt{ \frac{2}{3} \ln{(1 + x^2)} + C} $$

solves the differential equation

$$ \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{x^3}{y + yx^3}$$

However, this is an error and this $y$ does not solve the differential equation. Is there a simple typo that makes the problem workable?

Comment: I've solved my own question...

Changing $ y = \sqrt{ \frac{2}{3} \ln{(1 + x^3)} + C} $

and

$ \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{x^2}{y + yx^3}$ seems to do the trick.

Comment: Have you tried to differentiate y=23ln(1+x2)+C−−−−−−−−−−−−√ with respect to x? Make an attempt and add more detail to your question.

Comment: your book does have the wrong answer. Whatever answer you get, when you integrate you should back the original $y$ value

Answer (score 2):

$y = \sqrt{ \frac{2}{3} \ln{(1 + x^2)} + C}$  square both sides and differentiate and you get  $\displaystyle{2yy' = \frac{\frac{2}{3} \times 2x}{1+x^2}} $

$$
\begin{align*}
yy' &= \frac{2}{3(1+x^2)}\\ 
\Rightarrow  y' &= \frac{2}{3y(1+x^2)}\\
 &= \frac{2}{3y+3yx^2}
\end{align*}
$$

(Checked with the answer above to be correct by Wolfram [here](http://tinyurl.com/89o5pbx) )

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Differentiating 
$$y = \sqrt{ \frac{2}{3} \ln{(1 + x^2)} + C}$$
With respect to x should lead you to

$$y'(x) = \frac{2x} {{\sqrt {6} \ {(x^2+1)}}\ \sqrt{ \ln{(1 + x^2)}}}$$

That should help you for 
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{x^3}{y + yx^3}$$

Edit: just saw your comment how the original had an $x^{3}$ term rather than $x^{2}$.

Comment: This is not correct answer, technically if you integrate both sides you should get back the $y$ value.